# What do you call a member function that follows a member function and how do I write one?

Tags: c++, c++11

What do you call function that follows a member function and modifies the return value and how do I write one?

In other words how do I successfully write:

```
std::cout << box.getVolume().inCubicFeet();

std::cout << box.getVolume().inCubicCentimeters();
```

Comment: It's called method/member-function [chaining](http://jamie-wong.com/2012/02/01/stop-returning-void/).

Comment: Very similar to this is the concept of [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) where the methods return the `this`, which allows for method chaining. But given that you're returning a different class, it's not exactly the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that to work `getVolume()` needs to return an object of type `Volume` ( or even a reference to an object of type `Volume &`), so that whatever method follows you are able to invoke it on said object.
For instance:

```
class Volume{
    ...
    int inCubicFeet() const {
        //convert it and return it
    }
    int inCubicCentimeters() const {
        //convert it and return it
    }
};


class Box{
    Volume v; //volume object that is initialized somewhere 
              //(either in the constructor of Box or in a method like setVolume)
    ...
    Volume const& getVolume() const {
        return v;
    }
};
```

Comment: did you mean `Volume& getVolume(){..` or maybe `const Volume& getVolume(){..` ?

Comment: As a matter of fact, i didn't. Because it is not necessary, but it might be useful depending on the purpose and size occupied by a Volume instance

Comment: before your edit, the text said "...you need to return a reference.." which was not consistent with the code. However, now I have no complaints anymore ;)

Comment: I don't see how it would be a benefit. doesnt `return` make a copy anyways so that the object isnt destroyed at the end of the function scope?

Comment: @MM sorry, I edited before seeing this discussion. I too think that returning a non-const reference is bad, since it allows the (inadvertent) change of the underlying `volumeObject`. Always use `const` if possible.

Comment: I call it "elephant-style chaining".

Comment: I see the pretinance and accept the advice, thanks for improving this answer.

Comment: Returning by value has its merits, too. One could chain modifiers without affecting the original object: `box.Volume().addpercent(10).tocc().roundup()`... In cases like this with small PODs it's also not slower than returning references and potentially opens the door for better optimization, I suppose (because all objects are independent).

Comment: How is the int variable from 'box' class being passed into 'inCubicFeet()' 'Volume' class and what would I put in place of 'volumeObject'?

Answer (score 0):

`box.getVolume()` needs to return an *object* of a `class` for which a function `inCubicFeet()` is defined which returns a value for which `std::ostream` has an overloaded `<<` operator (although you are allowed to define your own overloads). For that second part, a `double` would suffice.

Comment: Perhaps mention the term "method chaining" or "function chaining", as that's what (part of) the pattern is called.

Comment: @Gerard: Isn't that what the C# quiche-eating set call it?

Comment: it's a pattern agnostic of the language. This being c++, we could come up with a cryptic 4 letter acronym. Perhaps 'FNCN' or 'MFMC'.

Comment: It can be any combination of 4 letters - then bacronym some meaning: Cf. RAII.

Answer (score 0):

It is called "member function of the return type". There is nothing special about those methods. The code could be written like this:

```
const Volume& v = box.getVolume();    // my guess on what the return type is
std::cout << v.inCubicFeet();
```

Comment: `const Volume& v` seems better. Or even `auto&& v`.

Comment: @Jarod42 `auto&&` would defeat the whole point of the snippets as it was just meant to show that that there is another type involved. However agreed for the `const&`